# How to send a mail to user by using Sitecore Rules

Tags: c#, sitecore

I am trying to send a mail to user by using Sitecore rules.
I created a rule in Item Saved event in Rules.
My Rule is like this

```
    "where user profile Fullname field is not empty
    send Newsletter Message 10T023615 e-mail"
```

but it doesn't make any sense.Please can anyone explain me how the rule works and when the Item saved event fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Rule` consists of 2 parts: a `Condition` and an `Action`.
The Condition part of your Rule you mention there is:

```
where user profile Fullname field is not empty
```

The Action part of your Rule is:

```
send Newsletter Message 10T023615 e-mail
```

When the rule runs and the Condition evaluates to True it will trigger the action. You'll need to have that rule trigger on some type of action of a visitor.
You can add rules for instance to specific components, to do personalization for example.

Just looking at your rule it would seem to me that for this type of thing you'd create an Engagement Plan. For more information on Engagement Plans, please take a look at [this article on doc.sitecore.net](https://doc.sitecore.net/products/email%20experience%20manager/creating%20and%20editing%20messages/walkthrough%20editing%20message%20engagement%20plans). This is a walkthrough for editing message engagement plans. This is written for Sitecore 8, if you're interested in an older version I know there's cookbooks available for engagement automation on [Sitecore's Develop Network](http://sdn.sitecore.net).

Comment: Thank you.How to run the rule

Comment: There's a lot of different ways to run rules. I would suggest running through the Rules Engine cookbook (http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%207/Rules%20Engine%20Cookbook.aspx) to get some more information on that.

Comment: Thank you sir.I already read the documentation but didn't found anything like how the rule works or how to run the rule.Based on my rule i am trying to creating a user in "User Manager".I am giving all fields including full name but message is not delivered to particular e-mail.My rule works here or not.Help me to solve this issue.

Comment: What you could do is hook into the user:created event instead of using the Rules Engine here. Possibly set the name of the newsletter message to send in an item if you need some flexibility there for instance. I don't think I would do this with the Rules Engine. 
If you do want to do it through the Rules Engine I'd suggest using Reflector/ DotPeek to check the <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.InsertRenderings.Processors.EvaluateConditions, Sitecore.Kernel"/> processor and taking it from there.